# Using TransactionScope in Service Layer for UnitOfWork operations

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope

Is my approach right to bundle all 3 dataprovider.GetXXX methods in a TransactionScope in the service layer as UnitOfWork?

Would you do something different?

From where does the TransactionScpe ts know the concrete ConnectionString?

Should I get the Transaction object from my connection and pass this Transaction objekt to the constructor of the TransactionScope ?

Service Layer like AdministrationService.cs

```
private List<Schoolclass> GetAdministrationData()
{

   List<Schoolclass> schoolclasses = null
   using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        schoolclasses = _adminDataProvider.GetSchoolclasses();
                        foreach (var s in schoolclasses)
                        {
                           List<Pupil> pupils = _adminDataProvider.GetPupils(s.Id);
                           s.Pupils = pupils;

                           foreach (var p in pupils)
                           {
                               List<Document> documents = _documentDataProvider.GetDocuments(p.Id);
                               p.Documents = documents;
                           }
                        } 

                        ts.Complete();
                    }


   return schoolclasses;
}
```

Sample how any of those 3 methods in the DataProvider could look like:

```
public List<Schoolclass> GetSchoolclassList()
        {
            // used that formerly without TransactionSCOPE => using (var trans = DataAccess.ConnectionManager.BeginTransaction())
            using (var com = new SQLiteCommand(DataAccess.ConnectionManager))
            {
                com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SCHOOLCLASS";

                var schoolclasses = new List<Schoolclass>();

                using (var reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Schoolclass schoolclass = null;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        schoolclass = new Schoolclass();
                        schoolclass.SchoolclassId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["schoolclassId"]);
                        schoolclass.SchoolclassCode = reader["schoolclasscode"].ToString();
                        schoolclasses.Add(schoolclass);
                    }
                }
                // Used that formerly without TransactionSCOPE => trans.Commit();
                return schoolclasses;
            }
        }
```

Comment: TransactionScope should typically be used when doing data modifications or other operation (non-db related) that should be an "all or nothing" kind of operation. Selecting data from database is really not a transaction. Besides, if you need all these results you should be getting multiple result sets in one query to the database. In your case, since you're not using stored procedures, you should have mutiple select statements in one query (CommandText). The DataReader will then have mulitple result sets that you can iterate over using the NextResult() method of the DbDataReader.

Comment: TransactionScope makes itself known (or vice versa) to the underlying ADO.NET provider, so that whatever you execute inside the scope/lifetime of the TransactionScope automatically participates in the transaction. As such, it is much easier to use than the classic "connection.BeginTransaction()" api.

Comment: @Shiv ok my sample was a bit dumb with the select... for update,insert,delete its valid. Yes I know about the .NextResult() method of the datareader, but there is one thing why I can not use it. Lets assume I get all Schoolclasses in the first select statement. how do you pass EACH schoolclassId of the resultset to the second select statement getting the pupils for EACH SchoolclassId ? I do not use store procedures. I use a simple Comment.Text = "Select .... fields from table"

Comment: sample: com.CommandText = "Select * FROM Schoolclass; Select * from Pupil; Select * from Documents"; This is a very simple sample in real I have a N:M relation from pupils to documents... @Shiv lets assume I have those 3 ResultSets in the reader and do 2 times reader.NextResult() am I right that I still have to compare the schoolclassId with the pupil.schoolclassId to know which pupil belongs in which schoolclass.Pupils collection ?

Comment: @Shiv the bad thing with the resultset would be I would have to get ALL Documents because at the moment where I construct the query with 3 Select statements I do not know each single Pupil Id related to the PUPIL_DOCUMENT table which agains refers to the DOCUMENT table. So as far I can see there is no ResultSet for me.

Comment: @msfanboy, without trying to go through every detail you've provided...use a join statement and you probably need only one resultset. If you're relying on doing single table selects all the time then you're not using a database for what it is really good at doing.

Comment: @Shiv You got it! Actually it was you who suggested to do 3 selecteds in a single query ;-) I do not do such stuff. I do 3 Left Joins on my 3 tables and get all schoolclas,pupil,document stuff see this:

Comment: com.CommandText = "SELECT schoolclassId,schoolclasscode,pupilId,firstname,lastname,street, postal,city,phone,email,extrainformation,gender,schoolclassId_FK,documentId,documentname,documentId_FK FROM SCHOOLCLASS LEFT OUTER JOIN PUPIL ON SCHOOLCLASS.schoolclassid = PUPIL.schoolclassId_FK LEFT OUTER JOIN PUPIL_DOCUMENT ON PUPIL.pupilId = PUPIL_DOCUMENT.pupilId_FK LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCUMENT ON PUPIL_DOCUMENT.documentId_FK = DOCUMENT.documentId"

Comment: @msfanboy, your sample code show multiple database calls: GetSchoolClasses(), then a bunch of GetPupils() then a bunch of GetDocuments(), then you show a sample of how the database calls look like. So what do you expect? ;)

Comment: @Shiv I expected that you are more smart than me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine - that's what `TransactionScope` is there for, to provide transaction control in your code (and this is a common pattern for UoW).

> From where does the TransactionScpe ts know the concrete ConnectionString?

It doesn't. That depends on your data access layer and doesn't really mean much to `TransactionScope`. What `TransactionScope` does is create a transaction (which will by default be a light-weight one) - if your data access spans several databases, the transaction will *automatically* be escalated to a distributed transaction. It uses MSDTC under the hood.

> Should I get the Transaction object from my connection and pass this Transaction objekt to the constructor of the TransactionScope ?

No, no, no. See the above. Just do what you are doing now. There is no harm in nesting `TransactionScope`s.

Comment: ok Oded, but I do not access several databases, just do update/delete/insert on Multiple tables - ok I know I do a select here... but just forget that for now ;-) -

Comment: @msfanboy - Not the point. You use it the same way with a single database. My answer stands...

Comment: @Oded So the TransactionScope class is also saving me from doing business layer save/store methods where I have always a transaction parameter right? Actually yes well so that class is very nice then hehe.